# Is there any method to encrypt/hide credential while sharing code which is accessible to the services

Tags: node.js, encryption

I am writing a nodeJs application; while I want to share the entire code with others, however, I want them to be accessible to the database&API by the `.env` file to test out all the functions and don't want them to know the exact key&secret inside the `.env`.

Is there any way I can encrypt or hide the `.env` while it is accessible?

Comment: No, there's no way.  Either share the credentials, or don't.